# The relationship between real negative eigenvalues and convergence rate for ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Let $\pmb{\delta}=\pmb{\delta}^\triangle$ be an equilibrium point for the following ODE ,
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial \pmb{\delta}(t)}{\partial t}=\pmb{F}(\pmb{\delta}) \ with  \  \
    \pmb{F}(\pmb{\delta}^\triangle)=\pmb{0},
\end{align*}
where $\pmb{F}: \mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is continuously differentiable and $\mathbb{D}$ is a neighborhood of $\pmb{\delta}^\triangle$. Let
\begin{align*}
    A=\frac{\partial \pmb{F}(\pmb{\delta})}{\partial \pmb{\delta}}\bigg|_{\pmb{\delta}=\pmb{\delta}^\triangle},
\end{align*}
and $\chi$ denotes eigenvalue of $A$. Then, if $\chi_i$ are real and $\chi_i<0, i=1, 2, \cdots, d $ for all eigenvalues of $A$, $\pmb{\delta}^\triangle$ is an exponentially stable equilibrium point of this ODE.

Based on the above, whether we have the following inequality?
\begin{align*}
e^{\min\chi(A)t}\|\pmb{\delta}(0)-\pmb{\delta}^\triangle\|
\leq
\|\pmb{\delta}(t)-\pmb{\delta}^\triangle\|
\leq 
e^{\max\chi(A)t}\|\pmb{\delta}(0)-\pmb{\delta}^\triangle\|.
\end{align*}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is generally false. Linear stability does not imply nonlinear stability. You would need additional assumptions on how close you start to the equilibrium point and how large the nonlinear components of $F$ are compared to the linear parts of $F$. For a somewhat technical example of such an argument, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303811/linear-instability-implies-nonlinear-instability